# What have we ruled out as far as planets orbiting Gliese 710 goes?

Tags: exoplanet

My thoughts are that, if we are still around 1.3 million years from now, we might actually be able to send a mission there. Will the spectrometers of the 30 meter telescopes that are coming on line soon be able to narrow this down?

Comment: The context for this is that Gliese710 is predicted to pass about 10000 AU from the sun in about 1.3 million years time.   Obviously it's not possible to speculate on what state humanity will be in in 1.3 million years (consider that 1.3 million years ago, modern humans hadn't even evolved yet).

Comment: I imagine (but don't know) that plenty of effort has been expended, with no success so far.

Comment: It is in the CARMENES survey, which claims to be able to detect planets that cause a 1m/s radial velocity of stars (about 2-earth-mass  planet in the habitable zone of an M-type dwarf star), and they have not detected any. It's not ideal, being fairly large, so it would move less in response to a planet. I don't know if the ELT will better this, or by how much.